# Customzing the "Add a Page"

Tags: web-part, template

I'm a newb when it comes to Sharepoint and my IT staff are not pros on the config end by any means either so I've had a challenging project.

I have made a page, that looks like this:
http://postimg.org/image/5r2du1h0v/

The menu bar at the top is part of the master page and some items as well that are not displayed above that. Everything below is part of the page content itself and can be easily edited by editing the page in the browser.

I want to turn this single page into a 'template' or something along that nature.  Basically others will be adding new 'subjects' and I want them to follow the same structure.

I'd like them to ideally to start with what that picture looks like and they can edit from there.  Even at this point, if when going to "Add a page" it started with this it would be fantastic. Keep in mind that any content from the photo would be edited to match the posters needs.

What exactly are my options?  I've tried "Save as Template" but have had no luck there.   Someone suggested going to Page Layouts/Design Manager and editing the "BlankWebPartPage.aspx" but I don't see Design Manager under Look&Feel and I don't see Page Layouts in SP Designer 2013.  The IT staff can't see any options in terms of access to give me to allow me to see these items.  I also have root access to the drive itself (so I can go manually edit files) and I can't find that file anywhere on the drive whatsoever.

What option do I have?  Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, **Page Layouts** are the way to go: http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-branding-101-branding-page-layouts